# How to show that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density $2e^{-x-y}$ over $0<x<y<\infty.$ Show that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

I am not sure how to proceed with such problems. From one of the answers in some post, I saw that we the goal is to give a counterexample to the following 
$$P(X\leq s,Y\leq t)=P(X\leq s)P(Y\leq t)$$ 
but since I am not sure how $X$ and $Y$ are individually distributed, I do not know how to apply this technique. Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: Can I say that since $f(x,y)\neq f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$, the random variables are not independent?

Comment: Yeah that works: see LucaMac's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, since you are given the density $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = 2e^{-x-y}$, you can calculate $$ f_{X}(x) = \int_{x}^{+ \infty} 2e^{-x-y} dy = 2e^{-2x}$$ for $x>0$.

$$f_Y(y) = \int_0^y 2e^{-x-y} dx = 2e^{-y} \cdot (1-e^{-y})$$
Thus $f_{(X,Y)} \neq f_X \cdot f_Y $ and so they are not independent.

Maybe my calculation are wrong, if it is the case I am really sorry.